# The variable used to store previous sheetID not working in Qlikview 12.4

Tags: qlikview

I have a variable defined as below:

```
=if(right(GetActiveSheetId(),4)='SH01',
or (right(GetActiveSheetId(),4)='SH02',
or (right(GetActiveSheetId(),4)='SH03',
or (right(GetActiveSheetId(),4)='SH04',
(right(GetActiveSheetId(),4), if(isnull(vPreviousSheetID),'SH01',vPreviousSheetID))
```

This variable is used to store Previous Sheet ID , it was working fine  on Qlikview Version 12.1 but after upgrading to 12.4 , its not working fine, its storing 'SH01'. Please guide me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the text escape handling changed. I tried this and it works when used as the On Leave Sheet Trigger

```
=if(right(GetActiveSheetId(),4)='SH01'
or right(GetActiveSheetId(),4)='SH02'
or right(GetActiveSheetId(),4)='SH03'
or right(GetActiveSheetId(),4)='SH04',
right(GetActiveSheetId(),4),
if(isnull('$(vPreviousSheetID)'),'SH01','$(vPreviousSheetID)'))
```

I also did this jsut for myself to make it more manageable

Define a variable in the srcipt
`set vSheetList = "'SH01','SH02','SH03','SH04'";`

and then use this on each sheet instead of the first definition for vPreviousSheetID:

`=if(match(right(GetActiveSheetId(),4),$(vSheetList)),  right(GetActiveSheetId(),4), if(isnull('$(vPreviousSheetID)'),'SH01','$(vPreviousSheetID)'))`

Then everytime you add a sheet you only have to add the new sheet nubmer to the list and paste this into the On Leave Trigger